# Sdk de Java en Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, ios, vscode, dart

Soy desarrollador de Android hace masomenos 2 años con Android Studio, y ahora quería empezar con Flutter pero tengo una duda y necesito saber que hacer para poder construir una app.

Necesito hacer una app conectada vía Bluetooth a dispositivos médicos.

El equipo de trabajo me envió los links del sdk (Android e iOS)

Eh visto ejemplos de como agregar las dependencias tanto en Android como iOS dentro del proyecto de flutter.

Pero no sé cómo agregarlas luego al archivo pubspec.yaml.

No se me da mucho una idea de si es necesario que el Sdk también tenga una versión en dart o si flutter puede hacer una conversión del sdk de Android a dart para poder utilizarlo en Flutter.

Entonces, en resumen:

Tengo un sdk para trabajar en mis apps. Tengo los links para agregar en dependencias.

La pregunta es ¿Como los agrego al proyecto de flutter para trabajar el Sdk con dart ?

Los sdk que debo utilizar son los siguientes:

```
Import SDK

dependencies {
        ...
        implementation 'com.github.elinkthings:AILinkSDKRepositoryAndroid:Tag'//Bluetooth library(must)
        implementation 'com.github.elinkthings:AILinkSDKParsingLibraryAndroid:Tag'//Parsing library (including algorithms), need to rely on Bluetooth library(not required, it is recommended to rely on)
        implementation 'com.github.elinkthings:AILinkSDKOtaLibraryAndroid:Tag'//OTA library, need to rely on Bluetooth library(not necessary)
}
```

Las dependencias anteriores necesito incorporarlas a flutter para trabajarlas con Dart. Ese es mi problema.

Ayúdenme amigos! Estoy atascado!
Actualmente uso VSCode

Comment: Bienvenido, Cuál es tu pregunta principal?, si deseas realizar un proyecto te sugiero preguntes por pasos, revisa [ask]

Comment: Ahi aclare mi pregunta, gracias!

Comment: Cuales son las dependencias?, estas se agregan a pubspec.yaml, pero cuáles son porque no se agregan mediante un url.

Comment: Hola Kalium, bienvenido, Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!, Este es un sitio   de preguntas y respuestas, las preguntas deben ser concisas y sobre un tema puntual, tu pregunta está basada en opiniones, por lo que seguramente será cerrada, trata de hacer algo, luego muestra que has h

Comment: Ahí agregue los datos a tu consulta

Comment: Puedes desarrollar un plugin https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Answer (score 0):

Existe la forma de interactuar con la capa nativa desde flutter, y es usando MethodChannel. Lo que significa que si quieres implementar un sdk para android, lo puedes hacer de costumbre, pero debes enviar la información a la capa de flutter.
Ahora yo te aconsejo que le des una vuelta a las bibliotecas existentes para satisfacer tus requerimientos, ya que de esa forma puedes encontrar soluciones para los distintos sistemas que compilaras.

Mira te doy un ejemplo
En este ejemplo yo implemente un sdk de un PDA para configurar lector y demases

Desde flutter

```
class QRPlatformChannel {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('app.example/qr_platform_channel');

  Future<void> lectorPDA() async {
    try {
      var result = await platform.invokeMethod('lector_qr');
      print(result);
    } catch (e) {
      // log.w(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Y desde android

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    private static final String CHANNEL = "app.example/qr_platform_channel";
    // Barcode2D barcode2D;
    BarcodeUtility barcodeUtility = null;

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            if (call.method.equals("lector_qr")) {
                                barcodeUtility = BarcodeUtility.getInstance();
                                barcodeUtility.setOutputMode(this, 0);
                                barcodeUtility.open(this, BarcodeUtility.ModuleType.BARCODE_2D);
                                barcodeUtility.enablePlaySuccessSound(this, true);
                                barcodeUtility.enableContinuousScan(this, false);
                                barcodeUtility.enableEnter(this, false);
                                barcodeUtility.enableVibrate(this, true);
                                result.success("Configurar PDA");
                            } else {

                                result.notImplemented();
                            }
                        });
    }

}
```